# Sed Command (unterminated 's' command)

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to add an argument to the flag batch start. This is the error it gives me. Any idea on how to fix this?

```
$ sed -i "s/batch_start.*/batch_start\ 1111/" /tmp/runfile
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Is that really the command you're running, or are you substituting variables into the `s///` command?

Comment: Some ideas: Try `''` instead of `""`, or try `\\ 1111` (double the backslash).  I am not at a terminal, but it seems like a possible quoting issue to me.  Good luck!

Comment: Are you executing the command directly, or trying to store it in a variable first? See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: How the `-i` option is handled depends on sed's version (`sed --version`). Some versions require `-i` to have an argument so try with `-i ''`.

Comment: Which version of sed do you use?

Comment: Instead of `-i` option, there is always old fashioned way: `sed "s/batch_start.*/batch_start\ 1111/" /tmp/runfile > tmpfile && mv tmpfile /tmp/runfile`

Comment: ssh remoteHost sudo sed -i "s/batch_start.*/batch_start\ 1111/" /tmp/runfile"
This is the complete command.

Answer (score 1):

The root problem is that the command is being sent over `ssh`; that means it's running through two levels of shell parsing, one on the local computer, then another on the remote computer. That means it goes through quote/escape parsing, application, and removal twice, so you need two "layers" of quoting/escaping.

The command in the last comment doesn't parse (mismatched quotes), but I can reproduce the error message with this command:

```
ssh remoteHost "sudo sed -i "s/batch_start.*/batch_start\ 1111/" /tmp/runfile"
```

This sort-of has two levels of quotes, but quotes don't nest, so it doesn't work. The local shell parses this as a double-quoted string `"sudo sed -i "`, then an unquoted section `s/batch_start.*/batch_start\ 1111/` (which contains an escaped space, so it'll remove the escape), then another double-quoted section: `" /tmp/runfile"`. Since there are no spaces between them, they all get passed to `ssh` as a single argument. You can see the post-parsing string by replacing `ssh remoteHost` with `echo`:

```
$ echo "sudo sed -i "s/batch_start.*/batch_start\ 1111/" /tmp/runfile"
sudo sed -i s/batch_start.*/batch_start 1111/ /tmp/runfile
```

...so that's the command the remote shell will execute. Since there's a space between `s/batch_start.*/batch_start` and `1111/`, they get passed to `sed` as separate arguments, and it treats the first as the command to execute (which is missing a close `/`) and the second as a filename.

Solution: there are many ways to correct the quoting. You can use the `echo` trick to see what'll get sent to the remote shell. I tend to prefer single-quotes around the entire command, and then just quote normally inside that (as long as the inner command doesn't itself contain single-quotes). In this case, that means:

```
ssh remoteHost 'sudo sed -i "s/batch_start.*/batch_start 1111/" /tmp/runfile'
```

which executes this on the remote computer:

```
sudo sed -i "s/batch_start.*/batch_start 1111/" /tmp/runfile
```

(note that I removed the escape on the space.)

Comment: Thanks so much. That really helped.